# Reversing original intention of attending an event

Tags: off-site-events

I was invited to attend a remote event with a few of my co-workers a few states away. I decided after some thought to attend as it might be a way for me to bond with my 2-3 closest coworkers and I might learn something interesting.

However the circumstances have changed and I would rather not attend. Who do I need to tell this too (I assume probably the HR person responsible, my boss, the coworker in question, and possibly the rest of the team) and how do I say this? As of now it seems that nothing has actually been purchased yet but it is likely to happen very soon.

I was hesitant originally because it required me to take a weekend and a half day of personal time to participate for the three days of the event (5/6 of the event time is on personal time). Additionally, while the topic relates to my job, it's not as related as it could be, it doesn't align to my personal interests. But I decided that the bonding would be worth it in the end and it'd be fun.

Unfortunately, one of the coworkers that was originally planning to attend is not. The other I learned was bringing his immediate family and probably will be rooming somewhere separate. It seems like now I might be alone for the drive to and from, before and after the event on the given days, and possibly even during the event as the other coworker and I will probably attend different portions of the event. I feel as though this will end up not being any fun and just being a stressful weekend as socializing with strangers without having any sort of friend or coworker is tough due to how anxious I get.

Answer (score 3):

You just tell those that need to know that you're not able to make it. Exactly like your other coworker did.

No need to go into the details of why you don't want to go.

Comment: When he declined he hadn't actually accepted, only saying he was interested and he should be free. I on the other hand accepted and have been approved. I figured there'd be some sort of social obligation to give a reason...

Comment: If you know travel hasn't been booked yet, a simple "Something came up and I will be unable to attend *event* on *date*" should suffice.